# Angular Percentage and Total calculation

Tags: html, angular, angular-material, angular8, angular-reactive-forms

I am using angular reactive forms. I have to calculate percentage and total and have to show in html UI. And it is like product billing.....  For example

My format of json is

```
{
    "amount": 10000.0,
    "balance": 0.0,
    "no": "1",
     percentage:2

"det": [
        {
            "amount": 1000.0,
            "desc": "ok",
            "remarks": "ok",
            "year": 2020
        },
        {
            "amount": 1000.0,
            "desc": "ok",
            "remarks": "ok",
            "year": 2020
        },
        {
            "amount": 0.0,
            "desc": null,
            "remarks": null,
            "year": 0
        }
    ],
```

I have to calculate the percentage and total amount of the amount inside of det array

my ngOnInit is

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.makeForm = this.fb.group({

      balance    : ['', Validators.required],
      amount     : ['', Validators.required],
      no         : ['', Validators.required],
      percentage : ['', Validators.required],

      details: new FormArray([
        this.det(), 
      ])
    })


det(){
      return new FormGroup({
        amount         : new FormControl(''),
        desc           : new FormControl(''),
        remarks        : new FormControl(''),
        year           : new FormControl(''),
    })}
```

How to calculate the percentage and total
Inside Table is editable field .....How to do that.... My doubt is How to calculate percentage and total in angular

```
percentage : 2                     /////percentage field


table


sl:no       desc         year           remarks      percentage      amount       %total      total      

1           none          2021            ok             2          10000         200       10200

2           none          2020            ok             2          1000          20         1020


                                                          Total             11220
```

Answer (score 1):

use a "getter" to total

```
get total()
{
   return this.makeForm && this.makeForm.value.det?
          this.makeForm.value.map(x=>x.amount).reduce((a,b)=>(+a)+(+b)):
          0
}
```

And in .html

```html
       <td>
        <input formControlName="amount">
       </td>
       <td>
        {{+makeForm.value.percentage*
            (+makeForm.get('det.'+i+".amount).value))/100 |number:'0.2-2'}}
       </td>
```

Comment: can you please give me an working model @Eliseo

Comment: I do have question in regards to mat table and it seems you have expertise here  can you please help me to resolve this mat table issue?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65347251/how-to-show-split-header-in-the-material-table-having-nested-group-of-data-in-an